# How to manipulate the following integral into a power series?

Tags: calculus, integration, power-series, substitution, hyperbolic-functions

I have to solve this integral:

$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{2(\cosh(x) -1)} \, dx $$

How do I convert this into a power series.

I already know that the result of that integral is $\frac{\pi^2}{3}$. That, at least to me, hints that this is a power series trick of sorts.

Thank you.

Comment: Try use that $cosh(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$ then use the series that represent the exponencial.

Comment: Actually, I started from $\frac{x^2 e^x}{(e^x - 1)^2}$ and simplified from there. I see now that this was a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int \frac{x^2}{\cosh(x) -1} \, dx$$

Trying integration by parts
$$u=x^2 \qquad \text{and} \qquad dv=\frac{dx}{\cosh(x) -1}$$
$$du=2x\,dx\qquad \text{and} \qquad v=-\coth \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$
$$I=-x^2 \coth \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+\int 2 x \coth \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\,dx$$
Integration by parts again
$$u=2x \qquad \text{and} \qquad dv=\coth \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\,dx$$
$$du=2 dx \qquad \text{and} \qquad  v=2 \log \left(\sinh \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)$$
$$\int 2 x \coth \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\,dx=4 x \log \left(\sinh \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)-4\int  \log \left(\sinh \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)\,dx$$ For the last integral, I am stuck but [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BLog%5BSinh%5Bx%2F2%5D%5D%2Cx%5D) knows !

Comining all of the above plus Wolfram Alpha result, assuming $a>0$
$$J=\frac 12\int_a^\infty \frac{x^2}{\cosh(x) -1} \, dx=$$ $$\frac{1}{2} \left(4 \text{Li}_2\left(e^{-a}\right)-a \left(a+4 \log
   \left(1-e^{-a}\right)-a \coth \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)\right)\right)$$ and a series expansion gives
$$J=\frac{\pi ^2}{3}-a+\frac{a^3}{36}+O\left(a^5\right)$$